# Time/space complexity of a non-binary tree traversal algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, tree-traversal, space-complexity

What would be the time and space complexity of a non-binary tree traversal algorithm that prints out every possible path in the tree starting from the root?

Comment: Depends on the traversal. But depth first search would do the job and hence can be done in the order of O(N) where N is number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of binary trees, the #edges = #vertices - 1. The traversal takes O(|E|) or O(|V|) time.

In case of non-binary trees, #edges = #vertices - 1 still holds true. So, traversal still takes O(|E|) or O(|V|) time.

Getting every possible path takes same amount of time as traversal = O(|E|) or O(|V|).

If you want to print all the stored paths, it could take O(length of the longest path * number of paths).

Total time complexity
=Traversal + Print
= O(|E|) + O(length of the longest path * number of paths).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!